# Organize my results in a table like a correlation matrix

Tags: r, unix, awk

I need to organize my results of correlation in a matrix, for example. I have a file like this:

```
trait1  trait2  GeCor   PCor
     a       b  -1.00   0.28
     b       c   0.40   0.45
     d       e  -0.39   0.35
     a       c  -0.39   0.50
     b       d   0.36   0.30
     a       d  -0.35   0.30
     b       e  -0.29   0.36
     a       e   0.26   0.33
     c       e   0.18   0.38
     c       d   0.04   0.31
```

And I need that file stay this way:

```
        a      b       c       d       e
a      -    0.28    0.50    0.30    0.33
b   -1.00     -     0.45    0.30    0.36
c   -0.39   0.40     -      0.31    0.38
d   -0.35   0.36    0.04      -     0.35
e    0.26  -0.29    0.18   -0.39     -
```

The symbol on the diagonal (`-`) only is that this space should be left blank. The `GeCor` are genetic correlation between `trait1` and `trait2`, these should be below of the blank diagonal, and `PCor` are the phenotype correlation between `trait1` and `trait2`, and should be above of the blank diagonal. Well, just to tell this database is just a sample and I have many more traits. I accept programming suggestions for unix or R. Thank you very much.

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs, actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve this problem  and people may be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: In fact, this is only a small part of the problem, I extracted the results of several other files one by one via linux programming, and I failed that part in question due to my vague knowledge in Linux. I tried a surreal setting. OK, so I did not explain, but somehow I have a great effort, but I just simplified my problem. And yes, you're right I did not think in this context where it seems I'm trying to earn this easily. Thank you and in the next time I will improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is time to post my solution with R.

First, with `read.table`, read in your original data into a data frame, say `x`. Then

```
n <- ceiling(sqrt(2 * nrow(x)))
NAME <- with(x, sort(union(unique(trait1), unique(trait2))))

z <- matrix(NA_real_, n, n, dimnames = list(NAME, NAME))
z[lower.tri(z)] <- with(x, GeCor[order(trait1, trait2)])
z[upper.tri(z)] <- with(x, PCor[order(trait2, trait1)])

#      a     b    c     d    e
#a    NA  0.28 0.50  0.30 0.33
#b -1.00    NA 0.45  0.30 0.36
#c -0.39  0.40   NA  0.31 0.38
#d -0.35  0.36 0.04    NA 0.35
#e  0.26 -0.29 0.18 -0.39   NA

## write to file "z.txt"
write.table(z, file = "z.txt", na = "-", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)

a   b       c       d       e
a   -       0.28    0.5     0.3     0.33
b   -1      -       0.45    0.3     0.36
c   -0.39   0.4     -       0.31    0.38
d   -0.35   0.36    0.04    -       0.35
e   0.26    -0.29   0.18    -0.39   -
```

Comment: Thank for your attention, and sorry I will re-formulate my question.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your script is calculating the names of the row and column indices instead of reading them from the input file? Why not just use whatever row/column names are in the input?

Comment: @EdMorton It could indeed be a problem if the traits (1 and 2) are not consecutive letters starting from 'a'. It could be done from the traits also with at low cost using  `order(x$trait1)` and `order(x$trait2)` in place of `letters[1:n]`

Comment: Yes, Ed the names are on the file.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, none of the GNU core utilities would solve this problem easily.  The manipulation of your data structure is not a simple re-arrangement.  Let me offer a generic solution, and then give you a solution using python; which would be the easiest language to implement in (least lines of code).

Essentially, if you treat trait1 and trait2 columns as your matrix indexes, you need to create a matrix of size NxN.  With N being the number of unique 'traits' - (i.e. a, b, c, d - N = 4).  Then using your original data structure, cells [a,b] = Pcor while [b,a] = GeCor.  You never specified any other order, so I'll assume none.  Therefore, we need to assume no structure or correlation between order of one row to another row.  This means we need to use hash indexing to store the correct values with the correct keys - i.e. ab = 0.28 and ba = -1.00.  Once we build the entire dictionary structure, we simply unroll it (in alphabetical order) and output the final data structure.

A simple functional decomposition (non object oriented), would break this into three distinct blocks.  Read in original table, fill diagonal cells, and output new data structure.

Here is a python2 implementation of this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import fileinput

finalStruct = {}
diagCh = '-'
delimiter = '\t'


# Build initial structure
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip()
    columns = line.split(delimiter)

    # Create first layer of dictionary inside dictionary
    if columns[0] not in finalStruct:
        finalStruct[columns[0]] = {}

    finalStruct[columns[0]][columns[1]] = columns[3]

    if columns[1] not in finalStruct:
        finalStruct[columns[1]] = {}

    finalStruct[columns[1]][columns[0]] = columns[2]

# Add '-' for diagonals
for currKey in finalStruct.keys():
    finalStruct[currKey][currKey] = diagCh


# Output final structure
for rowIndex in sorted(finalStruct.keys()):
    for colIndex in sorted(finalStruct[rowIndex].keys()):
        print finalStruct[rowIndex][colIndex], delimiter,

    print
```

If this code file was solution.py, and our input file was:

```
a   b   -1.00   0.28
b   c   0.40    0.45
d   e   -0.39   0.35
a   c   -0.39   0.50
b   d   0.36    0.30
a   d   -0.35   0.30
b   e   -0.29   0.36
a   e   0.26    0.33
c   e   0.18    0.38
c   d   0.04    0.31
```

And our input file was input.txt.  We can run this example as:

```
cat input.txt | ./solution.py

-   0.28    0.50    0.30    0.33    
-1.00   -   0.45    0.30    0.36    
-0.39   0.40    -   0.31    0.38    
-0.35   0.36    0.04    -   0.35    
0.26    -0.29   0.18    -0.39   -
```

Comment: I tried and it worked perfectly. Thank u for a new approach.

Comment: wrt `none of the GNU core utilities would solve this problem easily` - not sure why that's a consideration but it's absolutely trivial to solve this using the standard UNIX tool awk, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39738407/1745001, and can apparently be done in fewer lines of code than in python FWIW.

Comment: @EdMorton - I agree with awk; not to be pedantic, but awk is not a core utility.  I thought about using awk, but I decided python would be more readable - portable to other systems.  And lastly, my python code is two lines shorter than your awk code (not including whitespace, shebang, or comments).  However, I agree that awk/perl could certaintly solve this with less lines of code at a sacrifice to readability.

Comment: I wasn't saying awk is a GNU core utility (because I have no idea if it is or not), just that there's no reason to focus on that subset of tools. I can't imagine why you'd think python would be more portable or readable than awk. Your script is briefer because it doesn't produce the posted expected output. Obviously I could make the awk code briefer by removing the unnecessary curly brackets and I could make it briefer again by removing the statement that prints the row labels and the loop that prints the column headers so it'd then be equivalent to your python script and about 6 lines shorter

Answer (score 2):

Another approach in R, using packages `data.table` for reading data and `dplyr`:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("trait1  trait2  GeCor   PCor
a       b  -1.00   0.28
b       c   0.40   0.45
d       e  -0.39   0.35
a       c  -0.39   0.50
b       d   0.36   0.30
a       d  -0.35   0.30
b       e  -0.29   0.36
a       e   0.26   0.33
c       e   0.18   0.38
c       d   0.04   0.31")
#or df <- fread("myfile.txt")

library(dplyr)
data.frame(trait1=unique(c(df$trait1,df$trait2)), trait2=unique(c(df$trait1,df$trait2)),cor=NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% mutate(trait1=trait1, trait2=trait2, cor=GeCor, GeCor=NULL, PCor=NULL )) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% mutate(temp=trait2, trait2=trait1, trait1=temp, temp=NULL, cor=PCor, GeCor=NULL, PCor=NULL )) %>% 
  arrange(trait1, trait2) -> df_long

print.table(matrix(df_long$cor, nrow=5, dimnames=list(unique(df_long$trait1),unique(df_long$trait1))), na.print='-')

      a     b     c     d     e
a     -  0.28  0.50  0.30  0.33
b -1.00     -  0.45  0.30  0.36
c -0.39  0.40     -  0.31  0.38
d -0.35  0.36  0.04     -  0.35
e  0.26 -0.29  0.18 -0.39     -
```

Comment: Tested and approved

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    cell[$2,$1] = $3
    cell[$1,$2] = $4
    keys[$1]
    keys[$2]
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"

    printf "%5s", ""
    for (col in keys) {
        printf "  %-5s", col
    }
    print ""

    for (row in keys) {
        printf "%s", row
        for (col in keys) {
            printf "  %5s", ((row,col) in cell ? cell[row,col] : "- ")
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
       a      b      c      d      e
a     -    0.28   0.50   0.30   0.33
b  -1.00     -    0.45   0.30   0.36
c  -0.39   0.40     -    0.31   0.38
d  -0.35   0.36   0.04     -    0.35
e   0.26  -0.29   0.18  -0.39     -
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -ae '
if($. > 1)
{
    $h{"$F[0]$F[1]"} = $F[3]; $h{"$F[1]$F[0]"} = $F[2];
    push(@hh,$F[0]) if !$done{$F[0]}++;
    push(@hh,$F[1]) if !$done{$F[1]}++;
}
END
{
    print "\t".join("\t",sort @hh);
    foreach (sort keys %h)
    {
        ($k1,$k2) = /./g;
        print "\n$k1" if !$seen{$k1}++;
        print "\t-" if $k2 eq ++$k1;
        print "\t$h{$_}";
    }
    print "\t-\n";
}' ip.txt
    a   b   c   d   e
a   -   0.28    0.50    0.30    0.33
b   -1.00   -   0.45    0.30    0.36
c   -0.39   0.40    -   0.31    0.38
d   -0.35   0.36    0.04    -   0.35
e   0.26    -0.29   0.18    -0.39   -
```

- Input line is split based on space and saved to `@F` array
- If input line is greater than one, save 3rd and 4th column in hash with two combinations of 1st and 2nd column as keys
- Also save all unique 1st or 2nd column values in an array
- At end, print in required format